# T-SQL pattern matching with exceptions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dataexplorer

Here's a problem I've repeatedly encountered while playing with the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), which is based on T-SQL:

How to search for a string *except* when it occurs as a substring of some other string?

For example, how can I select all records in a table `MyTable` where the column `MyCol` contains the string `foo`, but ignoring any `foo`s that are part of the string `foobar`?

A quick and dirty attempt would be something like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyCol LIKE '%foo%' 
  AND MyCol NOT LIKE '%foobar%'
```

but obviously this will fail to match e.g. `MyCol = 'not all foos are foobars'`, which I do want to match.

One solution I've come up with is to replace all occurrences of `foobar` with some dummy marker (that is not a substring of `foo`) and then checking for any remaining `foo`s, as in:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE REPLACE(MyCol, 'foobar', 'X') LIKE '%foo%'
```

This works, but I suspect it's not very efficient, since it has to run the `REPLACE()` on every record in the table.  (For SEDE, this would typically be the `Posts` table, which currently has about 30 million rows.)  Are the any better ways to do this?

(FWIW, [the real use case](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/430351/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-stack-imgur) that prompted this question was searching for SO posts with image URLs that use the `http://` scheme prefix but do not point to the host `i.stack.imgur.com`.)

Comment: Are you playing with the hosted version, or are you downloading the data to play with on your local system? If you are downloading locally, or have the ability to if you didn't know that was an option, then you can add RegEx functionality via SQLCLR. For example, you could download the [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com/) library (which I wrote, but the RegEx stuff is in the Free version), install it into a `Utility` DB, and then use it in queries for this or other stuff :-).

Comment: @srutzky: I'm using the hosted DB. I suppose I could look into downloading the data, but a solution that works online would be preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of the ways given so far are guaranteed to work as advertised and only perform the `REPLACE` on a subset of rows.

SQL Server [does not guarantee short circuiting of predicates](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/) and [can move compute scalars up into the underlying query for derived tables and CTEs](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors).

The only thing that is ([mostly](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12945/3690)) guaranteed to work is the `CASE` statement. Below I use the syntactic sugar variety of `IIF` that expands out to `CASE`

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  1 = IIF(MyCol LIKE '%foo%', 
               IIF(REPLACE(MyCol, 'foobar', 'X') LIKE '%foo%', 1, 0), 
               0);
```

Answer (score 1):

A three-stage filter should work:

1. collect all rows matching '%foo%';
2. replace all instances of 'foobar' with a non-occurring string (such as '' perhaps);
3. Check again for matching '%foo%'

Here you only perform the REPLACE on potentially matching rows, not all rows. If you are expecting only a small percentage of matches, this should be much more efficient.

SQL would look like this:

```
;with data as (
    select * 
    from MyTable 
    where MyCol like '%foo%'      
)
select *
from data
where replace(MyCol, 'foobar', 'X') like '%foo%'
```

Note that a sub-query is required, as there are no expression short-cuts in SQL; the engine is free to reorder Boolean terms as desired for efficient processing within a singe query level.

Comment: doing all of this in the same SELECT will be just as fast

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: SQL does not have short-circuiting of Boolean expressions. The only way to ***guarantee*** that the Replace and test is done only on the rows already passing the first test is to nest the query. One cannot judge by any particular execution plan.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - That doesn't guarantee anything either.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thank you. At least it's a bug scheduled to be fixed *eventually*, whatever that means.

Answer (score 1):

This will be faster than your current query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE 
  MyCol like '%foo%' AND
  REPLACE(MyCol, 'foobar', 'X') LIKE '%foo%'
```

The REPLACE is calculated after MyCol has been applied, so this is faster than just:

```
REPLACE(MyCol, 'foobar', 'X') LIKE '%foo%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're only interested in finding instances of `foo` with spaces surrounding them

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM MyTable 
 WHERE MyCol LIKE 'foo %' OR MyCol LIKE '% foo %' OR MyCol LIKE '% foo'
```

Comment: Alas, this will not match e.g. `'a fooing fooer foos the foos'`, which I do want to match. Let me update my example in the question.

Comment: So you want to match fooing, fooer and foos but not foobar?

Comment: Yes. The real use case that prompted this question was actually finding posts with image URLs that use the `http://` scheme prefix but do *not* point to the host `i.stack.imgur.com`.